# Should this "Mananger" structure be refactored?

Tags: java

I have a simple question:

Presume that there are 3 classes:

```
 public class Client {}

 public class AccountsHandler {
 
    Map<int, Account> accountsList;    

    public void createAccount(Client client, int accountId) {
        
    }

    public void deleteAccount(Client client, int accountId) {
        
    }
 }

 public class Account {
    int id;
    String name;
 }
```

As you can see, a client can have multiple accounts, and each of the `AccountsHandler`'s method thus would have the `Client` obj as its parameters

Now my question is, should the `AccountsHandler` be made for each clients only ?

```
 public class AccountsHandler {

    HashMap<int, Account> clientAccountsList;    

    Client client;

    AccountsHandler(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void createAccount(int accountId) {
        
    }

    public void deleteAccount(int accountId) {
        
    }
 }
```

If this procedure is only suitable for certain situations, I would like to know what exact scenario would fit either of these 2 approaches.

I want to know when to use either of the 2 process

Comment: Is this an academic setting? In real-life applications, that data would _very probably_ all go into a database which very likely will shift your point of view on this.

Comment: @Fildor Wouldn't I still need some sort of map to store the accounts there ? I feel like depending on the database & queries alone can be a bit inefficient and ruins readability